# Why does invoking System.gc() lead to a significant decrease in memory usage?

Tags: java, spring, memory-management, memory-leaks, jvm

I have a long-running JVM Spring server application that undergoes continuous processing. I've noticed a gradual increase in memory usage over time, but it never leads to a JVM out-of-memory crash. However, when I manually generate a heap dump, I observe a significant drop in memory usage, returning to the initially expected levels. When i analyze the dump i dont see anything unusual because probably dump is generated with garbage collecetd memory. As i know this drop occurs because generating a heap dump triggers the garbage collector to work.

To test this behavior, I tried calling System.gc(), and it reproduced the memory drop. I'm curious about why this happens. **Why does JVM not perform this garbage collection automatically?** It appears that, for some reason, it doesn't do so without me explicitly forcing it to clear. But as i mentioned this does not cause JVM crash. Probably it releases that memory when it needs it. **This is an autoscaling application running on Kubernetes, and this behavior results in the unnecessary creation of additional instances due to the memory increase.**

**Is there a parameter which i can pass to JVM related to this behaviour?**

I expect JVM to clear memory automaticly without me explicitly calling System.gc()

Comment: There is an algorithm on when to trigger a gc, apparently the limits aren't such that the GC was deemed needed by the JVM.

Comment: How are you measuring memory usage?

Comment: @JohnBollinger i get total os physical memory with  (((UnixOperatingSystemMXBean) osBean).getTotalPhysicalMemorySize());

then i get free os physical memory with (UnixOperatingSystemMXBean) osBean).getFreePhysicalMemorySize();

i check the difference between and calculate memory in usage

Comment: @M.Deinum is there anything i can do to change this behaviour or should i?

Comment: Why should you change it? There is no out-of-memory and there is no performance issue, so why tamper with it? The GC will kick in when needed. GC tuning is a special kind of witchcraft (yes that is delibarate) you need to know which GC strategy is used and how to influence it. It might be that it works on one environment but gets worse on another.

Comment: You are not measuring what you think you are measuring, @YunusEmreGuneyStudent.  There are at least three confounding factors here: (i) other processes running on the system contribute to the memory load; (ii) you are looking at physical memory only, ignoring virtual memory; but most of all (iii) the amount of memory attributed to the Java VM is not the same thing as the amount of space occupied by live objects.  A process does not necessarily return memory to the operating system when it is freed.  Often the free memory remains assigned to the process.

Comment: This behavior leads to Kubernetes autoscaling initiating the creation of new nodes, even when it's not truly required. Any thoughts on this matter?

Comment: Java will expand to consume as much memory as you allow it.  If you don't wish it to use as much memory, limit its maximum heap size.

Comment: Bad Title: "Why does invoking System.gc() lead to a significant decrease in memory usage?" is not the same as "Why does JVM not perform this garbage collection automatically?"

Answer (score 2):

> **Why does JVM not perform this garbage collection automatically?**

Java does run the garbage collector automatically, at its own discretion.  The timing and effect of it doing so depends on many factors, and not all GC runs are the same.  Among other things, collecting unreachable objects makes more memory available to the VM, but that does not necessarily reduce the VM's memory usage from the OS's perspective.

Nor does manually requesting GC via `System.gc()` necessarily reduce the VM's memory usage from the OS's perspective.  Indeed, [its docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#gc()) make no specific promises, and expressly disclaim several:

> When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine
> has made a best effort to reclaim space from all unused objects. There
> is no guarantee that this effort will recycle any particular number of
> unused objects, reclaim any particular amount of space, or complete at
> any particular time, if at all, before the method returns or ever.
> There is also no guarantee that this effort will determine the change
> of reachability in any particular number of objects, or that any
> particular number of `Reference` objects will be cleared and enqueued.

You go on to say,

> **This is an autoscaling application running on Kubernetes, and this
> behavior results in the unnecessary creation of additional instances
> due to the memory increase.**
>
> **Is there a parameter which i can pass to
> JVM related to this behaviour?**

This is a function of your particular VM.  There are no standard VM options relevant to the question, but your particular VM probably has options that affect GC strategy and timing, and maybe some that affect the total amount of memory that the VM will use.  You should check the documentation for your VM for more information.

If you happen to be using the Oracle / OpenJDK VM then Oracle's fairly extensive documentation on GC tuning will be of interest to you.  Choose the version of that documentation that applies to your particular version of the VM.  For example, if you are using Java 21 then you're looking for https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/gctuning/introduction-garbage-collection-tuning.html#GUID-326EB4CF-8C8C-4267-8355-21AB04F0D304.